# how to open a link in in new tab in console application?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-console-components

In console app, I created a custom console component(page) consist of links.If I click on any of them,the link has to open with in the page.How to do this?

Comment: So you want same page but a new console tab right?

Comment: Did you check this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_openconsoleurl.htm

Comment: I have done with openPrimaryTab() method in integration.js.Thanks @ santanu Boral

Answer (score 1):

If you want your page to work both in and out of the console, you can adopt something like the following. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) is a brief explanation of why you should use IIFE structure.

```
(function (c, d, w) {
    // select all anchor tags
    // cache array size for performance if there are many links
    // define a click listener function once for reuse
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        anchorCount = anchors.length,
        dynamicLink = function (e) {
            if (c.isInConsole) {
                // in the console, you don't want to change the page
                // instead, open a new primary tab and switch focus to it
                e.preventDefault();
                c.openPrimaryTab(/*tabId*/ null, this.href, /*isActive*/ true);
            }
            else {
                // out of the console, do the redirect
                w.top.location = this.href;
            }
        };

    // on ready, add click listeners
    // if you don't wait for page load, they will get overwritten
    d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        for (var index = 0; index < anchorsCount; index++) {
            anchors[index].addEventListener('click', dynamicLink);
        }
    });

}(sforce.console, document, window));
```